# Regarding WCF SOAP based web service and servlets

Tags: java, web-services, wcf, servlets

I am new to WCF SOAP based services. I have a webpage which takes 3 fields and validates them in Javascript. After validation it sends them to a servlet. Now, in servlet I need to call a web service which is a WCF based SOAP service.

How should I proceed? Is it possible to make the call?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to call, it doesn't matter it's a WCF web service. You just need to write a client to call the web service and use the client from within your servlet code.

There are enough SOAP web services frameworks out there that allow you to generate a client. You could keep it simple by [using a JAX-WS client generated with `wsimport`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html#bnayx) or even manually building the message for the call by using something basic as [SAAJ](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbhr.html#bnbhs).

Comment: Hi can u tell me in detail  for the same... I have a servlet to call the webservice...here on stack. I have gone through the link it seems not to have hello service and my wsdl file is remotely located.please help