# Calling WCF webservice from Java Servlet

Tags: c#, java, web-services, wcf, servlets

Hi very naive to wcf client programming...my first program only
I have a servlet which needs to call a wcf service .
I need a detailed explaination of this as to how it is being done..as per my research its similar to calling soap request but with some proxies and client and configuration bindings

as of now , I know that I have a .svc?wsdl file which works in Wcftest client.exe perfectly

Even referred this question [Regarding WCF SOAP based web service and servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23443471/regarding-wcf-soap-based-web-service-and-servlets)

but it did not had certain files

The wsdl file is located remotely.

Comment: Shouldn't be an issue IF the data types you use in your Data Contracts exist in Java as well.

Comment: What are data contracts

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to do the same thing a few days ago. I used [this](http://hoonzis.blogspot.co.at/2011/07/consuming-wcf-services-with-java-client.html).

You need to add this to the Web.config of the wcf service.

```
   `<behavior name="NeutralBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
    `
```

Then in your eclipse project right click and add a new web service and add the wsdl url and it will generate for you all the files you need to use the service. If something is not clear please ask

Comment: I have a .svc?wsdl file remotely located . Will this help. I did tried earlier to create using eclipse.-->new -->web services --> webservice client and I provided wsdl url and then it gave error

Comment: You mean to say now I will have to edit the wsdl or config file to suit my java servlet client..

Comment: is the wcf service running while you are doing this?

Comment: What does that mean ... the service is already being running and I get an error in eclipse when  I try to create new webservice client project as IWAB0399E Error in generating java from wsdl

Comment: can you put the Web.config from the wcf project?

Comment: Its been remotely made and I have only wsdl link which I tested in wcf test client and it worked properly it does have client.dll.config . Will it help

Comment: Sir please let me know at the earliest

Comment: I got some thin like this <behaviour name = "somename.Service1Behaviour"> rest is samere